# Can a friend of A<T> be also a friend of A<A<T>>?

Tags: c++, c++14, friend, friend-function

Consider the following code:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T> class Container;
template<typename T> Container<Container<T>> make_double_container(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>&);

template<typename T>
class Container {
    std::vector<T> v;
    friend Container<Container<T>> make_double_container<T>(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>&);

public:
    Container() {}
    explicit Container(std::vector<T> v) : v(v) {}
};

template<typename T>
Container<Container<T>> make_double_container(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& v) {
    Container<Container<T>> c;
    for(const auto& x : v) {
        c.v.push_back(Container<T>(x));
    }
    return c;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    auto c = make_double_container(v);
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler tells me that:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'Container<Container<T> > make_double_container(const std::vector<std::vector<T> >&) [with T = int]':
main.cpp:27:37:   required from here
main.cpp:8:20: error: 'std::vector<Container<int>, std::allocator<Container<int> > > Container<Container<int> >::v' is private
     std::vector<T> v;
                    ^
main.cpp:20:9: error: within this context
         c.v.push_back(Container<T>(x));
```

Which I believe to be correct, because `make_double_container` is friend of `Container<T>`, but not of `Container<Container<T>>`. How can I make `make_double_container` work in this situation?

Comment: Question is theoretically interesting. But vectors of vectors are, sort of, evil, so it defeats the purpose mostly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Clearly, you can make every specialization of `make_double_container` a friend:

```
template <typename U>
friend Container<Container<U>> make_double_container(const std::vector<std::vector<U>>&);
```

If you want to keep friendship to a minimum without partial specialization or the like, try

```
template <typename> struct extract {using type=void;};
template <typename U> struct extract<Container<U>> {using type=U;};
friend Container<Container<typename extract<T>::type>>
     make_double_container(const std::vector<std::vector<typename extract<T>::type>>&);
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88ceeca122c7b853).

Comment: I precisely wanted to avoid `f<U>` becoming friend of `A<T>` (first code-snippet). I think your second code snippet gives "precise" friendship while avoiding the hassle of writing many specialised `f`'s. Clever trick, +1!

Answer (score 3):

Defining `make_double_container` as a template function of `S` seems to make it compile and work.

```
template<typename T>
class Container {
    std::vector<T> v;

    template<class S>
    friend Container<Container<S>> make_double_container(const std::vector<std::vector<S>>&);

public:
    Container() {}
    explicit Container(std::vector<T> v) : v(v) {}
};
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bdc23a0451a2125b

when the compiler sees something in the structure of :

```
template<class T>
class X{};
```

when you specify what `T` is, it instanciates the class and replaces everything with the typename `T` to the specified type.

when you write

```
 Container<Container<T>> c;
```

`T` is in fact `Container<T>`, and `make_double_container` turnes into

```
Container<Container<Container<T>>> make_double_container(const std::vector<std::vector<Container<T>>>&);
```

and then (inside main) into

```
Container<Container<Container<int>>> make_double_container(const std::vector<std::vector<Container<int>>>&);
```

by changing the friendship into :

```
 template<class S>
    friend Container<Container<S>> make_double_container(const std::vector<std::vector<S>>&);
```

you force the compiler to figure out what is `S` from the template of `Container<Container<T>>` , and then it figures out the right type of `S`, which is `int`

Comment: Your solution would work, but it would make e.g. `make_double_container<std::string>` a friend of `Container<Container<int>>`.